# React Testing Library + Router

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-router, react-testing-library

I wanted to render different routes in a same test file.

For example, this is my `cooltest.test.js`

```
import { App } from '../App.js'
import { renderWithRouter } from './renderHelper'

test('Example - Render View', async () => {

  const route = '/dummy/Seguros'
  const { getByText, getByTestId } = renderWithRouter(<App />, { route })

  getByTestId('dummyHeader');
  getByText(route)
});

test('Example - Render Another View', async () => {

  const route = '/dummy/Ayuda/Seguros'
  const { getByText, getByTestId } = renderWithRouter(<App />, {
    route
  })

  getByText(route);
});
```

And I got a file that has this `renderHelper.js`:

```
export const renderWithRouter = (
  ui,
  {
    route = '/',
    history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] }),
  } = {}
) => {
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <Router history={history}>{children}</Router>
  )
  return {
    ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper }),
    // adding `history` to the returned utilities to allow us
    // to reference it in our tests (just try to avoid using
    // this to test implementation details).
    history,
  }
}
```

The thing is it always goes to my homepage or `"/"` site.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user on the react-testing discord helped me identify the problem.

If anyones has this problem, it was a problem regarding the router and where it was placed.
For some reason router was placed directly on `app.js` file instead of `index.js`.

This is the correct way of having the router in `index.js`

```
import { App } from './App.js'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App/>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And `app.js` file should be something like

```
function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} exact component={Landing} />
        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/dummy/:number?`} component={Dummy} />
        <Route path="*" exact component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Again, thanks to "ljosberinn | Gerrit Alex" for the help.